# Share data between multiple topologies in Apache Storm

Tags: real-time, apache-storm, distributed-computing, hadoop-streaming

I have basic question about Apache Storm. 
Can we share data between two different topologies? So if I have topology A which has

### Spout_A >> Ab1 > Ab2 > Ab3

bolts and the I want a new topology B in want to reuse the output of Ab2 like

### Spout_B >> Bb1 > Ab2 > Bb2.

Note:These two topologies mentioned above are different Storm applications.

Comment: this might have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690691/communication-between-several-storm-topologies)

Answer (score 2):

Ab2 can write to some message bus (additional bolt) in addition to the regular operation of Ab3

The second topology can listen to that bus